# Hide div based on <select> option type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select dropdown which is dynamically populated and displays a list of servers.

I've currently got a script to display a padlock / open padlock to show if an option requires a password, an exert of this script shown below:

```
var has_password=true;
if(stations[i].Encryption =="none") has_password=false;
if(stations[i].Quality==100) img=
(has_password?"/images/pass.png":"/images/nopass.png");
```

What I would like to do is hide the html password input field if the selected option doesn't require a password but I don't think my approach is correct:

```
if(stations[i].Encryption =="none");
$("#password-div").hide();
else
{
$("#password-div").show();
```

Comment: The `hide()` `show()` is correct, you need to attach an `onchange` event to your select so you can then do the hiding/showing of your div

Comment: Your approach will work given that you will attach the appropriate listeners. What is the problem you are facing right now?

Comment: If you show us your `html` that would be useful also.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.. this is a demo I found on w3schools

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

That should give you an idea for the onchange event. You have the hide() and show() correct. Just add the onchange event now.

Comment: I've been able to add the onchange event and get it to display the type of encryption in a label but not able to hide div yet, will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: If you can create a dev of it I can take a look at it and help you. Use codepen.io or something like that. Otherwise show your new code you're working with and I'll take a crack at it.